# Need to access instance of service inside HostBuilder configured inside the same HostBuilder().ConfigureServices

Tags: dependency-injection, .net-core

Is it possible to access instance of DI configured services inside `HostBuilder()` configuration?

here is what I meant:

```
return new HostBuilder()
    .UseOrleans((cntx, builder) =>
    {
        builder.ConfigureApplicationParts(parts =>
        {
            // This is where I want to access instance of IMyService
            // in order to help Orleans builder to configure Orleans properly
        }
    })
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddSingleton<IMyService, MyService>();
    })
    .RunConsoleAsync();
```

Comment: @Nkosi I want Interface to specific Type mapping and instantiation logic to be in the single place, i.e. inside .ConfigureServices(...), and operate by IMyService inside UseOrleans(..), if it makes sense

Comment: In case this turns out to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), what is it that you are ultimately trying to achieve that you need access to that service in that delegate? In case there is some workaround.

Comment: Are you trying to create some startup task?

Comment: @Nkosi sorry for not providing enough details, I've just updated my question. In short, `IMyService` service execution results will help `builder` to configure the app, however I can't use regular Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration here, my service does some action besides returning configuration data, so it's not a regular configuration provider

Comment: Is `IMyService` used anywhere else other than in that builder delegate? You need to clarify what it is you actually are trying to do.

Comment: I'm trying to set up Orleans, and it needs some configuration data for that,  some of data are only accessible through legacy IMyService which implementation I do not have much a control of, I can only instantiate it and use it to get some data and this data will be fed to Orleans builder for proper configuration, like connection string, list of clusters, their names, and whatever else is needed for the configuration, do not even know all them upfront

Comment: Can you not create the instance externally of the builder and just use it in the configuration delegate? That is why I asked if that service is needed elsewhere that it has to be in the service collection. If the only reason for adding it is to be able to use it in configuration then it does not need to be in the service collection.

Comment: yes, I can have an instance of it in the configuration delegate, run all required methods, and move data to standard ms configuration builder, and then use only standard configuration inside UseOrleans(..). It means having bit more moving parts and code, but if you're saying there is no direct way, and it's the only way to utilize and instance of IMyService inside Orleans builder, I'm Ok to move forward with it

Comment: After going through their source code on GitHub https://github.com/dotnet/orleans/tree/0d577240e5e356fa0adfc9f4630d0171fb3fb5b3/src The only Hosting extensions that have access to deferred factory delegates that accessed the service provider was what I showed in the linked answer. So far I have not found any other access points.

Comment: ok then, thank you for your help! at least you directed me to good workaround

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case this turns out to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and you are you trying to create some startup task, there is a [`AddStartupTask`](https://github.com/dotnet/orleans/blob/0d577240e5e356fa0adfc9f4630d0171fb3fb5b3/src/Orleans.Runtime.Abstractions/Hosting/SiloBuilderStartupExtensions.cs#L153) extension

```
return new HostBuilder()
    .UseOrleans((cntx, builder) => {            
        //Add a startup task to be executed when the silo has started.
        builder.AddStartupTask((sp, token) => {
            // access instance of IMyService
            IMyService service = sp.GetRequiredService<IMyService>();

            //...use service as needed

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        });
    })
    .ConfigureServices(services => {
        services.AddSingleton<IMyService, MyService>();
    })
    .RunConsoleAsync();
```

Comment: cool, good to know about this feature, very helpful, however I wonder how I can use results of `IMyService` execution outside of the task, but inside the builder? please see my latest comment to the question, and updated question. Thanks!